# Start model browser in Forge viewer collapsed when loading several models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have tried to start the model browser with all nodes collapsed when loading several aggregated models, but it do no collapse all nodes. Is there any way to do this?

Try the code below on these model: https://wallabyway.github.io/federatedmodels-v7/

```
var ext = NOP_VIEWER.getExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure')
ext._modelstructure.options.startCollapsed = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one instead. The ModelStructralPanel will read options in its constructor only.

```
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container, {startCollapsed: true});

var ext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure');

// or 
// viewer.unloadExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure');
// var ext = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure', {startCollapsed: true});
```

Workaround:

Add this code snippet before opening the modelstructure panel.

```
var ext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure');
ext._modelstructure.addVisibilityListener( show => {
    if( show && (!ext._modelstructure.uiCreated) ) {
        ext._modelstructure.tree.delegates.forEach( d => ext._modelstructure.tree.setAllCollapsed( d, true ) )
    }
});
```

Comment: The suggested solution gives a "callback is not a function" error. I also tried to unload the extention and load it again with startCollapsed set to true, bit it do not work. Any outher suggestions?

Comment: My apologies, there is a typo, please check my updated answer

Comment: This certainly looks right, but I still do not get the browser collapsed. Neither with it set in GuidViewer3D or loading the extention.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with this option. I'm checking with our engineering team, and will get back A.S.A.P. Meanwhile, you can use this workaround: `ext._modelstructure.tree.delegates.forEach( d => ext._modelstructure.tree.setAllCollapsed( d, true ) )`

Answer (score 0):

When creating the viewer, pass the following option to it:

```
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container, {modelBrowserStartCollapsed: true});
```

It should cascade until reaching the model browser.

**Background**

The option "modelBrowserStartCollapsed" is passed on from the Viewer3D constructor up until the ModelStructureExtension, where it changes name to "startCollapsed" as it is passed to the ViewerModelStructurePanel.

```
proto.restoreDefaultPanel = function () {

            var config = this.viewer.config;
            var options = {
                docStructureConfig: config.docStructureConfig,
                hideSearch: (0, _src_compat__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.isMobileDevice)(),
                excludeRoot: config.modelBrowserExcludeRoot,
                startCollapsed: config.modelBrowserStartCollapsed // HERE
            };

            var modelTitle = config.defaultModelStructureTitle || 'Browser';
            var panelInstance = new _src_gui_ViewerModelStructurePanel__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ViewerModelStructurePanel(_objectSpread(_objectSpread({},
                options),
                (0, _src_gui_ViewerModelStructurePanel__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.generateDefaultViewerHandlerOptions)(this.viewer)),
                modelTitle);
            this.setModelStructurePanel(panelInstance);
        };
```

The source for ViewerModelStructurePanel shows that it takes the option "startCollapsed" as stated, among other options.

```
function ViewerModelStructurePanel(viewer, userTitle, ops) {
    ...
    options.startCollapsed = options.startCollapsed !== undefined ? options.startCollapsed : false;
```